# How to add content/string containing special character in file using ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

Problem Statement:
I want to update the file `/app/opt/MicroStrategy/MSIReg.reg_bkp` with content `"DSNotUseUnicodeForPT"=dword:00000001` under the line matching `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Castor]`.

I have created the below playbook task to use three variables:

```
- name: Add the entry as per our requirement
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: "{{ FILE_PATH_TO_CHANGE }}"
    insertafter: "{{ STRING_TO_MATCH }}"
    line: "{{ STRING_TO_ADD }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0664'
    state: present
```

The above variables I am passing as extra variables as below but the file is not getting updated. Can someone please help me with possible reasons?

```
FILE_PATH_TO_CHANGE=/app/opt/MicroStrategy/MSIReg.reg_bkp
STRING_TO_MATCH=[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Castor]
STRING_TO_ADD="DSNotUseUnicodeForPT"=dword:00000001
```

Command ran is: `ansible-playbook edit_file.yml -u username -e "FILE_PATH_TO_CHANGE=/app/opt/MicroStrategy/MSIReg.reg_bkp  STRING_TO_ADD="DSNotUseUnicodeForPT"=dword:00000001" STRING_TO_MATCH=[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Castor] --ask-pass`

Update: Contain of `/app/opt/MicroStrategy/MSIReg.reg_bkp`

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Castor]
"ClusterMembers"="hostnames"
"ClusterName"="abcd"
"DSHostName"=""
"DSMaxConn"=dword:000003e8
"DSNumAggregateThreads"=dword:00000004
"DSNumDecompressThreads"=dword:00000001
"DSNumDeserializeThreads"=dword:00000004
"DSNumReceiverThreads"=dword:00000001
"DSPort"=dword:00007621
"HomePath"="/app/opt/MicroStrategy/IntelligenceServer"
"IgnoreAllExceptions"=dword:00000000
"MaintenanceClusterMembers"="hostnames"
"MaintenanceModeEnabled"=dword:00000001
"ProcessAffinity"=""
"UseServerOSLocaleinFallback"="0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Instances]^M
"DefaultInstanceName"="CastorServer"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Instances\CastorServer]
"AsymmetricClustering"=dword:00000001^M
"ClusteringInUse"=dword:00000001^M
"MetaDataDBEncryption"="UTF8"^M
"MetaDataDatabaseVersion"="-1"^M
"MetaDataODBCDriverLibraryName"="<MySQL_ODBC_DIR>/libmyodbc8w.so"^M
"MetaDataODBCDriverVersion"="3.52"
"NumberOfNodesInCluster"=dword:00000002
```

Comment: I see you pass `STRING_TO_MATCH=[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Castor]` can you show us the content in your `MSIReg.reg_bkp ` ?

Comment: will this be acceptable for you? `STRING_TO_MATCH: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`? seems like those `[]` is being assumed as a list. And you really can't escape it if you are passing that value in a variable.

Comment: @JBone- added the contents of `MSIReg.reg_bkp`.

Comment: @JBone - The file contains the key [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...] multiple times. that's why I want it to be matched exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with passing `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...]` was that it was being treated like a `List` so I had to make this variable value to just `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` without `[]`. This works but I am not sure if you like this modification for your `insertlineafter` value.

Here is the playbook

```
---
- name: SO test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    FILE_PATH_TO_CHANGE: /home/user100/Documents/ansible/testso3.txt
    STRING_TO_MATCH: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    STRING_TO_ADD: '"DSNotUseUnicodeForPT"=dword:00000001"'
  tasks:
  - name: write in file
    lineinfile:
      path: "{{ FILE_PATH_TO_CHANGE }}"
      insertafter: "^.*{{ STRING_TO_MATCH }}.*$"
      line: "{{ STRING_TO_ADD }}"
      mode: '0664'
      state: present
```

and the file before the play

```
[user100@zini-1880 ansible]$ cat testso3.txt 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Castor]
"ClusterMembers"="hostnames"
"ClusterName"="abcd"
"DSHostName"=""
"DSMaxConn"=dword:000003e8
"DSNumAggregateThreads"=dword:00000004
"DSNumDecompressThreads"=dword:00000001
"DSNumDeserializeThreads"=dword:00000004
"DSNumReceiverThreads"=dword:00000001
"DSPort"=dword:00007621
"HomePath"="/app/opt/MicroStrategy/IntelligenceServer"
"IgnoreAllExceptions"=dword:00000000
"MaintenanceClusterMembers"="hostnames"
"MaintenanceModeEnabled"=dword:00000001
"ProcessAffinity"=""
"UseServerOSLocaleinFallback"="0"
[user100@zini-1880 ansible]$
```

and after the play

```
[user100@zini-1880 ansible]$ cat testso3.txt 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicroStrategy\DSS Server\Castor]
"DSNotUseUnicodeForPT"=dword:00000001"
"ClusterMembers"="hostnames"
"ClusterName"="abcd"
"DSHostName"=""
"DSMaxConn"=dword:000003e8
"DSNumAggregateThreads"=dword:00000004
"DSNumDecompressThreads"=dword:00000001
"DSNumDeserializeThreads"=dword:00000004
"DSNumReceiverThreads"=dword:00000001
"DSPort"=dword:00007621
"HomePath"="/app/opt/MicroStrategy/IntelligenceServer"
"IgnoreAllExceptions"=dword:00000000
"MaintenanceClusterMembers"="hostnames"
"MaintenanceModeEnabled"=dword:00000001
"ProcessAffinity"=""
"UseServerOSLocaleinFallback"="0"
[user100@zini-1880 ansible]$
```

if you want to not have the `vars` in your play-book, you can remove them here and pass as command line arguments as you did in your original post.